# TestNG + Spring + Power mock Unit test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, powermockito

I have a Spring based application and am in the process of unit testing it. I'm using TestNG for unit tests. For my test i need to make use of PowerMockito to mock some static methods. I also need to make use of a test spring config file for only my unit test.

I'm unable to write my unit tests combining all the three i.e. TestNg, PowerMock and Spring.

I can combine TestNG and Spring by extending the class AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests, however cant mock static methods, instead it executes the actual static method. Something like the below:

```
@PrepareForTest(MyUtils.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:config/test-context.xml"})
public class MyImplTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

.....

}
```

I can combine TestNG with PowerMockito by extending the class PowerMockTestCase. But then the test spring config files are not resolved. Something like the below:

```
@PrepareForTest(MyUtils.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:config/test-context.xml"})
public class MyImplTest extends PowerMockTestCase{

.....

}
```

Is there any way for me to write my unit tests combining all the three, i.e. TestNg, PowerMockito and Spring context?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than extending `PowerMockTestCase`, have you tried using the `PowerMockObjectFactory` by writing a method like below?  Then you can extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`.

> ```
> @ObjectFactory
> public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
>     return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
> }
> ```

This is suggested by the [Powermock GitHub docs](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage).

Comment: Anybody got solution to this ?